# how do I create a maven project for apache cxf wsdl first

Tags: maven, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I want to create a apache cxf maven project from scratch using a wsdl. I need to use the wsdl2java. I can not find an archetype for wsdl first. When I try

mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.apache.cxf.archetype:

I see only these. Is there not an archetype for wsdl first? If not can some recommend the most efficient approach? Thanks

Choose archetype:
1: remote -> org.apache.cxf.archetype:cxf-jaxrs-service (Simple CXF JAX-RS webap
p service using Spring configuration)
2: remote -> org.apache.cxf.archetype:cxf-jaxws-javafirst (Creates a project for
 developing a Web service starting from Java code)

Comment: I have exactly the same question. My WSDL is programmatically generated and I use wsdl2java too. I need an appropriate archetype to use. If you find convenient solution, could you share it, please ?

Answer (score 0):

I always create submodule for generated wsdl. Eclipse has a problem with paths - and this module do not need to be compiled many times.

For client:

```
<properties>
    <wsdl.dir>${basedir}/src/main/resources/axis2</wsdl.dir>
    <generateServerSide>false</generateServerSide>
    <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${sourceRoot}</sourceRoot>
                            <defaultOptions>
                                <bindingFiles>
                                    <bindingFile>${wsdl.dir}/binding.xml</bindingFile>
                                </bindingFiles>
                            </defaultOptions>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${wsdl.dir}/first.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <packagenames>
                                        <packagename>com.company.gen.first</packagename>
                                    </packagenames>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                                        <wsdlurl />
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin> <!-- for idea/eclipse -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${sourceRoot}</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

For server:

```
            <execution>
                <id>first</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <generateServerSide>${generateServerSide}</generateServerSide>
                    <generateAllClasses>${generateServerSide}</generateAllClasses>
                    <generateServicesXml>${generateServerSide}</generateServicesXml>
                    <generateServerSideInterface>${generateServerSide}</generateServerSideInterface>
                    <wsdlFile>${wsdl.dir}/first.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    <packageName>com.company.gen.first</packageName>
                    <unpackClasses>true</unpackClasses>
                    <syncMode>sync</syncMode>
                    <namespaceURIs>
                        <namespaceURI>
                            <uri>http://uri.company.com</uri>
                            <packageName>com.company.gen.first</packageName>
                        </namespaceURI>
                    </namespaceURIs>

                </configuration>
            </execution>
```